# Make function type for the structure field

Tags: go

Can i set up function type for structure's field?

I need something like:

```
type MyStruct struct {
  Callback func(int)
}
```

Thank you

Comment: It seems like we should first ask whether it is possible to have a callback function in Go.  That was just answered by nmichaels.  Now that we know it is possible, it should be trivial to put inside a struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, functions are first class things in Go. You can declare a [function type](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types) anywhere you could put any other basic type like an integer.